# headerTemplate in JavaScript instead of Wrapper for Kendo-UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui

How can I write this in javascript instead of using the MVC Wrapper?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.List)
      .Name("grid")
    .Columns(c => { 
        c.Bound(e => e.ID); 
        c.Bound(e => e.Nom).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { colspan = 2 }); 
        c.Bound(e => e.Nb).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style= "display:none;" }); 
    })
)
```

I started with the following code to experiment, I know it is not an exact
match to the attributes mentioned above, but how can I set
HeaderHtmlAttributes and Headertemplate for columns with javascript for the Kendo grid?

```
$("div#kendogrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        columns: [
             {
                 field: "ID",
                 title: "Nr Id",
                 headerTemplate: "sample template text col 1",
                 width: 100
             },
             {
                 field: "Nom",
                 headerAttributes: {
                     "class": "myHeader",
                     style: "text-align: right"
                 },
                 width: 200
             }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, `HeaderHtmlAttributes` is specified using [`columns.headerAttributes`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnsheaderattributes-object) and the equivalent to your `HeaderTemplate` is [`columns.headerTemplate`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnsheadertemplate-string). See the links for documentation:

- http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnsheaderattributes-object
- http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnsheadertemplate-string

The translation of your original code would be:

```
$("#kendogrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns   : [
        {
            field: "ID"
        },
        {
            field           : "Nom",
            headerAttributes: {
                colspan: 2
            }
        },
        {
            field           : "Nb",
            headerAttributes: {
                style: "display:none"
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: This is an new field to me. My problem is, that the headerTemplate and heaterAttributes have no effect on the final result.  When use the wrapper, the colspan und display none works great. When i use the javascript version, no effect happens.

Comment: I've edited the answer for adding the direct translation of your original code using `colspan: 2` and `style="display:none"`: check it!

Comment: gracias, but sorry, it does not work.  I copied the sample code excatly but all I get are 3 column headers width the same width, the headerAttributes seem to have absolutely no effect. I added a 4th column to test that I am not seeing cached content and I used current IE and Chromium browsers to test...

Comment: Please, check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/TEPFM/3/). I´ve just tested it in Chrome but it should work on other browsers as well.

Comment: Gracias!  It works!! JSFiddler is a great way to prove something. We used an older Kendo version, with the current one as used in jsFiddle, it worked like a charm. Gracias Emiliano, you saved my day!

Comment: Can we use above example for rowspan as well ?